# How can you calculate number of functions in a module when exporting/importing a custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Taking an instance of exporting these two functions in JS

module.js

```
const add = (a,b) => {
    return a+b;
};

const sub = (a,b) => {
    return a-b;
};

module.exports = {add, sub};
```

new.js

```
const {add, sub} = require('./module');

console.log(add(5,4));
console.log(sub(5,4));
```

Help, if I was to count how many functions am I importing on new.js file.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to apply every function that I import on two integers say 5,4. Since there can be more than 2 functions that I'll import, maybe we can loop through the number of functions imported. So that's why I was just tryna figure out the number of functions imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be interesting to know what you are trying to achieve as it is somewhat unusual, but it should be somewhat easy to get what you are after.

You can for example import everything from `'./module'` as an object and then count the keys or similar in the imported object to get number of functions.

So for example:

```
const importedFunctions = require('./module');

console.log(Object.keys(importedFunctions).length)
```

Edit:
I saw your reply in the comments. To extend it a bit further to call all imported functions with some values you could do something like this:

```
Object.values(importedFunctions).forEach((fn) => fn(5, 4))
```

Comment: Appreciate your help mate. I was trying to apply every function that I import on two integers say 5,4. Since there can be more than 2 functions that I'll import, maybe we can loop through the number of functions imported. So that's why I was just tryna figure out the number of functions imported. Anyways your idea did worked thanks <3